# Mysterious `1 in XAML Datatype

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics

I have no idea what to call this, so it may have already been addressed numerous times.

I have a wrapper class for a collection:`public class TreeCategory<T> : IEnumerable<T>`

In my `xaml` I am using the class in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as follows:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="m_CategoryTemplate"
     DataType="{x:Type local:TreeCategory`1}"   <--- WHAT IS THIS?!
     ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryCollection}" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

So my question is, when I build using `local:TreeCategory` the build fails, as the project complains it does not know what the class `TreeCategory` is. However if I use:

```
TreeCategory`1
```

then the project builds fine.

What is the `1, why is it necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.basetype.aspx

> Generic types are formatted with the name of the type followed by a grave accent ("`") followed by a count of the generic type arguments.

So by removing the `` `1 `` you're actually saying the type is `TreeCategory`and not `TreeCategory<T>`